# Convert spark dataframe to list

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Below is a spark dataframe

```
 FileName                   Status
+--------------------------+------------+
 Address20200803093116.csv  Success
 Address20201012112805.csv  Success
 Address20201012103745.csv  Success
```

[image: link to original image]

I want to get the FileName column from the DataFrame and store it in a list.

I have tried the below way but I am getting an error:
(*local variable 'list' referenced before assignment*)

```
fileNameList = list(filesNamesDF.select('FileName').toPandas()['FileName'])
```

Note: I don't want to use any actions like collect

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does your code contains a variable called `list`? It seems that's confusing Python.

Comment: Yeah.. It's not producing any error for me .. The code looks fine here

Comment: dsk, when i am running in individual cmd its working fine, but when i am put the same in code it is giving error

Comment: provide me any alternative way, without using action methods

Comment: Finally I got to know that if we want to convert dataframe to list we have to use some actions.